# use the ultralytics's yolov8 in Docker，“module 'cv2' has no attribute 'setNumThreads'”

Tags: python-3.x, docker, opencv, yolov8

when I "from ultralytics import YOLO" in Docker, it tell me "ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file". I change the opencv-python to opencv-python-headless the solve this question, but a new error occurred, "module 'cv2' has no attribute 'setNumThreads'", need to install opencv-python to solve it...How do I solve both problems at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include a minimal reproducible example